# Offsetting prefab tiles to generate Isometric map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to generate an Isometric map using 2d sprites as prefabs to create a base layer grid. In later iterations the position of the tile will allow the user to walk a character over etc (chess style game)

However I don't really understand the math behind getting the rows to offset correctly to achieve the results of a seamless isometric map;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IsometricMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int mapSize = 10;
    public GameObject tilePrefab;

    public int TileID = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }

    void GenerateMap()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize; y++)
            {
                if ((x < mapSize / 2 || x < mapSize / 2 || y < -x + mapSize * 3 / 2) && ((y < mapSize / 2 || y < x + mapSize / 2) && (x < mapSize / 2 || x < y + mapSize / 2)) && (y > mapSize / 2 || y > -x + mapSize / 2))
                {
                    tilePrefab.transform.name = "Tile: " + TileID++ + " [" + x + "," + y + "]";
                    Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The tile itself is 64x64 and as you can see only half of the tile is taken up with artwork. Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

Moreover and I know I should perhaps asks this is a separate question, but I know eventually this map shape will form a rhombus, but is there a way that I can make the map from a square instead?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try to google unity built-in isometric tilemaps

Comment: The only issue with using unitys tilemap is that I would like the user during runtime to be able to change the type of tile.on click.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html